# Want to see some words before open slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show the first 20-30 words even on closed Toggle. My code is below.

On the output page, I want to show only a few words at first and then when someone clicks on the icon or button, it should show the complete content, and when clicked again, it should again show only the first 20-30 words.

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#abdptext13").click(function(){
    $("#abpanel13").slideToggle(1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

CSS:

```css
#abpanel13{
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  max-width:600px;
  padding-left:25px;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="#droptext" id="abdptext13"><img src="images/textdrop_03.png" width="35" height="62" align="right" id="flip"></a>
</div>
<div id="abpanel13">
Click to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down 
panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick 
to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick 
to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide 
down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down 
panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down  
panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick 
to slide down panelClick to slide  down panelClick to slideClick to slide 
down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to   slide 
down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down 
panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick 
to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick 
to slide  down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide 
down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have modified the above code snippet, removed the extra div and included a flag. The code snippet displays the text based on pixels. Hope this satisfies your requirement.

```js
var down = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var initHeight = $("#abpanel13").css('height');
  $("#abpanel13").css('height', '50px');

  $("a#abdptext13").click(function() {

    if (!down) {
      $('#abpanel13').animate({
        height: initHeight
      }, 'slow', function(e) {});
      down = 1;
    } else {
      $('#abpanel13').animate({
        height: '50px'
      }, 'slow', function(e) {});
      down = 0;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#abpanel13 {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div>
    <a href="#droptext" id="abdptext13">Click Here</a>
  </div>
  <div id="abpanel13">
    Click to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick
    to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick
    to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick
    to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick
    to slide
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello Steven Dsoza,
Thanks for your answer but it is not working for me at all..
Atchully I want it like an image of arrow, when someone click on it, somewhere on page, a peragraph open smoothly, and when click again, it close but should let open 50-60px and rest get close...

Comment: "When clicked on the link, it opens the paragraph and on next click it closes the paragraph and keeps only 50-60px (currently the above is 15px) of the whole div block" - is this what you required? I guess the above code does the same. Please let me know what is not working for you as in the demo its working fine.

Comment: Hi Djmhim, Please refer to the modified code. I guess this should help.  Instead of slideToggle, you can use animate for the same. Modified the js to animate

Comment: Hello Steaven Dsouza
It's working perfect,, Only one thing, I want height auto not height: '500px'
Because some content is more than 500px and some are less than 500px. 
I am very very very thankful to u for helping me

Comment: Hello Steaven Dsouza,
I have already Accepted :D But just one help I need you more, At one place, you put Height 500px but I want it auto and when I put auto, it don't work, Can you please fix just this one for me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Now working perfecttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt.
Thanks you sooooooo much Steven Dsouza

Answer (score 1):

This snippet may satisfy your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var content = $("#abpanel13").html();
  var c = content.substr(0, 30);
  $("#abpanel13temp").html(c);
 $("a#abdptext13,#abpanel13temp").click(function(){
    $("#abpanel13").slideToggle(1000);
    
    $("#abpanel13temp").slideToggle(0);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#abpanel13{
padding: 10px;
display: none;
max-width:600px;
padding-left:25px;
text-align:justify;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="#droptext" id="abdptext13">Click Here</a>
</div>
<div id="abpanel13temp">
</div>
<div id="abpanel13">
Click to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down 
panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick 
to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick 
to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide 
down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick to slide down 
panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down  
panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick 
to slide down panelClick to slide  down panelClick to slideClick to slide 
down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to   slide 
down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide down 
panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slideClick 
to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick 
to slide  down panelClick to slideClick to slide down panelClick to slide 
down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide down panelClick to slide
 </div>
```

Comment: Hello Divyesh,
It's not smooth as it should, Can I have any solution to make it smooth open and close? At one time, abpanel1temp and abpanel1 appear both when we click on close.
Thanks in Advance